# Animate scrollTop but I can't use $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 'slow');

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, scrolltop

I am very new to jQuery so please don't mind me.

**I have this style**

```
html, body{
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

**And this script**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#guide-wrap').scrollTop($('#main').position().top);
});
```

So when the window loads, it jumps to `div` with id `main`
**I want it to animate** but since I have  `height: 100%; overflow: auto;` I cannot use this script:

```
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 'slow');
```

Or maybe I don't know how to do it. I know it may look very obvious to you guys but I am very new and I've google a lot before decided to post here. Please anyone help me.

Comment: It not animated and with `overflow: auto` the `scrollTop: 0` cannot find `#main`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 'slow');` is perfectly valid code for an animated scroll. However, it makes no sense to have an animation to scroll to the top of the page on a `$(document).ready()`, as a page will **automatically** be at the top by default.

If you're looking for the scrolling to trigger on a **hyperlink** click, you need to remember to pass **[`e.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)** to the click event to prevent the default behaviour. If the link is pointing to the same page (such as with `#`), it will 'jump' to the top unless this behaviour is prevented.

Here's a working example (scroll down to see the link):

```js
$(".scroll-top").on("click", function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 'slow');
});
```

```css
.tall {
  height: 200vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="tall">Top of the page</div>

<a href=# class="scroll-top">Scroll Up</a>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Hello Obsidian Age, Thanks for simple but works answer. The e.preventDefault(); does solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $("#main").offset().top }, "slow");
```

Comment: Hello BrandonW, thanks for the answer. That look like it should work but I don't know why, it does nothing. I reloaded the page but nothing seem to happen.

Comment: It depends on the use case. It would be rare to use this on page load, like the browser actually reloads at a lower position of the page, which is unreliable. Or you are using a framework like ember. It would be more relevant to us e.preventDefault() in a hyperlink or fire the action on a button click.